# Loading file from /src/main/resources

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML schema file in /src/main/resources/vast_2.0.1.xsd.

I need to load it and use it to validate my XML file.

This is what's happening:

```
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI);
        File schemaFile = new File("/src/main/resources/vast_2.0.1.xsd");

        try {
            Schema schema = scehmaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            Source sourceXMLFile = new StreamSource(validationRequest.xmlInputStream);
            validator.validate(sourceXMLFile);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            responseEngine.addFailedCheck("NON_VAST_COMPLIANT", "Does not meet VAST 2.0 XML schema specifications");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // should not reach here
        }
```

For some reason, after the  `File schemaFile = new File...` line, it ceases to run (using print statements). Am I loading the file incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your directory structure that you are using maven. In maven project, src/main/resources is always in the classpath so you need to specify just the file name without the path. Try this:

```
    File schemaFile = new File("vast_2.0.1.xsd");
```

Comment: So the problem seems to be `SchemaFactory scehmaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI);`. The process just ends right after this line.

Comment: @srirachablender To help yourself, you need to print the stacktrace in exception blocks. It will help you to understand what is going wrong.